# Ansible multiline escape slash in path

Tags: ansible

I want to create a variable which has a "/" but it gets escaped when using muiltiline.
Below is my example code

```yaml
---
- name: "Problem with backslash in multiline"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: "Init path variable"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        path_var_ok: "/tmp/ansible_test_file"
        path_var_fail_1: "
         /tmp/ansible_test_file"
        path_var_fail_2: '
         /tmp/ansible_test_file'
        path_var_fail_3: >
         "/tmp/ansible_test_file"

    - name: "Debug"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "[{{ path_var_ok }}] <=path_var_ok"
          - "[{{ path_var_fail_1 }}] <=path_var_fail_1"
          - "[{{ path_var_fail_2 }}] <=path_var_fail_2"
          - "[{{ path_var_fail_3 }}] <=path_var_fail_3"
```

Output:

```
...
TASK [Debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "[/tmp/ansible_test_file] <=path_var_ok",
        "[ /tmp/ansible_test_file] <=path_var_fail_1",
        "[ /tmp/ansible_test_file] <=path_var_fail_2",
        "[\"/tmp/ansible_test_file\"\n] <=path_var_fail_3"
    ]
}
...
```

As you can see only `path_var_ok` is ok. The others have spaces or escapes.

Using ansible: `ansible [core 2.15.0]` and `python version = 3.11.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I`am stupid.

`"` => caused the backslash as it tried to escape it.

Simply remove `"` in path_var_fail_3.

```
path_var_fail_3: >
         /tmp/ansible_test_file
```